# How to set needle type in std::binary_search

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I have the following simple program that will binary_search for an item:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Record
{
public:
    Record() = default;
    Record(std::string name, int data) : mName(name), mData(data) { }
    std::string mName;
    int mData = 0;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::vector<Record> recs;

    recs.emplace_back(Record("1", 1));
    recs.emplace_back(Record("55555", 2));
    recs.emplace_back(Record("333", 3));
    recs.emplace_back(Record("qwertyuiop", 4));
    recs.emplace_back(Record("22", 5));
    recs.emplace_back(Record("4444", 6));

    std::cout << "Unsorted:" << std::endl;
    for (auto& rec : recs)
    {
        std::cout << "Name: "  << rec.mName << " Data: " << rec.mData << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::stable_sort(recs.begin(), recs.end(), [](const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) -> bool
    {
        return lhs.mName.length() < rhs.mName.length();
    });

    std::cout << "Sorted:" << std::endl;
    for (auto& rec : recs)
    {
        std::cout << "Name: " << rec.mName << " Data: " << rec.mData << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (std::binary_search(
        recs.begin(), 
        recs.end(),
        Record("qwertyuiop", 4),
        [](const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) -> bool 
    {
        return lhs.mName < rhs.mName;
    }))
    {
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

How can I search the vector of Records based on another type of T? For example std::string instead of Record?

Something like:

```
 if (std::binary_search(
            recs.begin(), 
            recs.end(),
            "qwertyuiop",
            [](const Record& lhs, const std::string& rhs) -> bool 
        {
            return lhs.mName < rhs.mName;
        }))
        {
            std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
        }
```

Is what I want - basically I don't want to construct a Record to search for it as this presents a performance issue for me.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that with the standard library. I would implement the binary search on my  own - its about 10 lines of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function object type that handles heterogeneous comparisons:

```
struct comp_t
{
    bool operator()(Record const& lhs, std::string const& rhs) const {
        return lhs.mName < rhs;
    }

    bool operator()(std::string const& lhs, Record const& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs.mName;
    }
};
```

Then you can call `binary_search` like this:

```
std::binary_search(recs.begin(), recs.end(),
                   std::string("qwertyuiop"),
                   comp_t{})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an `implicit` constructor to convert `std::string` to `Record` and an operator to convert `Record` to `std::string`.

```
operator std::string() const {
    return mName;
}

Record(std::string name) : mName(name), mData(int()) {}
```

or you can convert your existing constructor to this

```
Record(std::string name, int data = int()) : mName(name), mData(data) {}
```

But anyways you'll need to create a `std::string` object to search.

```
/// create std::string object from "qwertyuiop"
if (std::binary_search(recs.begin(), recs.end(), std::string("qwertyuiop"), 
    [](const Record & lhs, const std::string & rhs) -> bool 
        {
            return lhs.mName < rhs;    /// rhs is a std::string type
        })) {
    std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/0f16GE demo.